# Cannot find files in Object storage from Watson Studio Modeler Flow

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio

I'm working on Tutorial for Watson studio machine learning using MNIST data set.

([This tutrial](https://dataplatform.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/ml-canvas-nnd-mnist-tutorial.html))

In Step2: I run into the error that I cannot fix by myself...

As this is code-less approach, let me attach the screenshot.

[image]

In the Image Data setting dialog, I can successfully select my bucket ("chmnist-1") where I uploaded the data file.

However, as I marked in the picture, those data files cannot seen from the editor at all, thus I cannot proceed the following steps in the tutorial.

I guess I've made a fundamental mistake, but  have no idea why 'there are no files',　although there are actually files in the chmnist-1 bucket content (as is shown in the right-hand side in the above picture)

Any advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I attempted this, was able to get the files from my bucket.
1. Make sure you are looking at the same Cloud Object Storage service which i believe you must be since you have the bucket listed but just double check.
2. If this has something to do with how this connection was created(the credentials used for connection) then try to create one more connection from that screen and see if that pulls your files.
3. one more is to generate a writer credentials from COS from IBM Cloud and then create the connection manually , Add to Project -> Connection -> COS.
I hope you are not using COS infra.

Comment: Charles 's option 3 worked!     By some reason , the grey check mark does not appear here, so let me tentatively  put this remark instead ,showing my appreciation and "accept" to this wonderful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Charles' advise was put as comment not as answer, thus I cannot accept it... 
Let me put answer by myself.  Charles' option 3 was worked well.  Thanks